# Expression for polynomial in $k[x,y]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Let $k$ be any field. For any polynomial $f \in k[x,y]$ apparently one can write $f(x,y) = f_0(x) + f_1(x)y + (x^3 - y^2)g(x,y)$. Why is this the case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $R$ is any commutative ring and $f \in R[y]$ is a monic polynomial of $y$-degree $n$, then we can do polynomial division: Modulo $(f)$ every polynomial in $R[y]$ can be reduced to a (unique) polynomial of degree $<n$. If $f$ has the form $y^2-r$, this particularly easy; we just replace each $y^2$ by $r$, $y^3$ by $yr$, $y^4$ by $r^2$, etc, so that you end up with a polynomial which is linear in $y$.

Now apply this to $R=k[x]$ and $f=y^2-x^3$.

Comment: "and $f$ ... is a monic polynomial"

Comment: Yep, I just missed that!